# How can cmake detect misspelled variable names on command line?

Tags: cmake

My CMakeLists.txt can take variables and values when the user specifies them on the command line in the usual form -Dname=value. E.g.

```
% cmake -DmyVariable=someValue ..
```

How can CMakeLists.txt detect variables that aren’t actually relevant, e.g. in case the user mispells them:

```
% cmake -Dmyxvarble=someValue ..
```

For example, can CMakeLists.txt process each defined variable on the command line sequentially, thereby spotting misspelled variable names?

I’m running cmake version 3.18.0-rc2. Thanks!

Comment: By default `cmake` should warn you about unused cli variables. I.e. `--no-warn-unused-cli` is an option.

Comment: cmake output can be very verbose, difficult for users to spot a misspelled (hence unused) variable in this way I think. I would prefer to exit with an error in this case if possible.

Comment: For such users, write your own wrapper with handy command line options. Or tell them to use ccache or other gui. || `How can cmake detect misspelled variable names on command line?` I do not see other way then: you would have to have a list of all possible options and all set variables and compare both lists. Note that the user may also set `-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS` and other cmake variables. Overall, not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You could query the cache entries of the toplevel dir and match against patterns of expected entries. Note though that this is not easy to maintain, since functionality like `find_package` relies on cache variables.

```
set(CACHE_VARIABLE_WHITELIST
    MyProject_BINARY_DIR
    MyProject_IS_TOP_LEVEL
    MyProject_SOURCE_DIR
    ...
)

get_directory_property(CACHE_VARS DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} CACHE_VARIABLES)

foreach(CACHE_VAR IN LISTS CACHE_VARS)
    # fatal error for any non-advanced cache variable
    # not in the whitelist and not starting with CMAKE_
    get_property(IS_ADVANCED CACHE ${CACHE_VAR} PROPERTY ADVANCED)
    if (NOT IS_ADVANCED AND NOT CACHE_VAR MATCHES "^CMAKE_.*" AND NOT CACHE_VAR IN_LIST CACHE_VARIABLE_WHITELIST)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Unexpected cache variable set: ${CACHE_VAR}")
    endif()
endforeach()
```